# SELECT rows with time 30 minutes or less?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have found ways on google to select rows within X amount of days, but I have a `datetime` column in my SQL Server 2008 table and would like to get the rows that have a `datetime` within the last 30 minutes.

Can anyone show me how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
WHERE column >= DATEADD(mi, -30, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2):

Use [DateAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

```
select * from
yourtable
where DateCol > DateADD(mi, -30, GetDate())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) or [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)