# How to use DATEADD in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem and I can't figure out the solution. With a previously asked question ([SELECT rows with time 30 minutes or less?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459608/select-rows-with-time-30-minutes-or-less)) I tried to make my COUNT(*) function work but I can't make it work. Anybody an idea?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM g_ad_view WHERE ad_view_time >= DATEADD(mi, -30, GETDATE())
```

And this is the error I get back:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION 18RVS15.DATEADD does not exist

Comment: What database are you using?  If not SQL Server or Sybase, then you are using the wrong syntax.

Comment: MySQL, I already thought so but since w3 was saying the same thing I thought it was me. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The MySQL syntax is:

```
WHERE ad_view_time >= now() - interval 30 minute
```

Answer (score 17):

DateAdd is missspelled: It must be DATE_ADD (with underscore). See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: i got following error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-7, GETDATE())' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `customers` where date_of_birth >= DATE_ADD(day,-7, GETDATE()))

Comment: @Karthik use DATE_SUB instead.

Comment: When you google it, dateadd() is def a thing for some kinda SQL engine.

Answer (score 2):

you can use DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 minute)

Comment: I offer a correction:  To utilize a 30 minute difference, CURDATE() should be changed to NOW(), which produces minutes and seconds.


NOW(): The date and time is returned as "YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS"
for 
CURDATE(): only date is returned "YYYY-MM-DD"